# I'm trying to compare the exact differences between ftp two modes using the packets captured using wireshark

Tags: ftp, wireshark, packets, passive-mode

I've captured packets in (ftp two modes ) the active and passive mode using Wireshark

Now I'm trying to compare and state the exact differences between those two modes using these packets...

What points should i be looking in particular ?

Explanation with an example would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you want to know how Active and Passive modes are different, read the RFC.

Comment: My assignment is to figure out the differences between two modes after capturing the packets in each mode seperatly